# enumerate in 2-3 columns

Tags: enumerate

If possible, how can i display like attached image : 2 columns of enumerate (Number 3&4) or 3 columns (5&6)

My code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm]

\begin{enumerate}
\item
     ..................... XXX
%\vspace*{1.5cm}
\item
   .....................  XXX
\end{enumerate}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following MWE, I have used the `multicols` environment from the `multicol` package in order to split the contents of the `tcolorbox` into two or three columns.

In oder to save sone time, you could also replace `.....................` by something like `\dotfill\enspace`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=15cm]
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm]
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  \dotfill\enspace XXX
\item  \dotfill\enspace XXX
\item  \dotfill\enspace XXX
\item  \dotfill\enspace XXX
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]