# change space between columns and rows of multicols and enumerate

Tags: multicol

i want to edit space between columns or rows of multicols.

Ex from [enumerate in 2-3 columns](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480510/enumerate-in-2-3-columns/480517#480517)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}


\begin{tcolorbox}[width=15cm]
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to increase od drecrease the horizontal space between the three clumns, you can alter the value of `\columnsep`. In order to change the vertical space between the items you can use the `itemsep` option provided by the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{20pt}


\begin{document}


\begin{tcolorbox}[width=15cm]
\begin{multicols}{3}
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=20pt]
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\item  ..................... XXX
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank for your solution. If i have 5 different begin/end multicols in my code and i want to set 5 different columnsep, ex: 10 pt, 20pt...50pt. How can i definite it? thanks

Comment: You can use a new `\setlength\columnsep{<length>}` command before every `\begin{multicols}` to use a different horizontal spacing for every multicols environment.